# Problem with converting .ascx to razor syntax

Tags: razor

I have a lot of problem for converting .ascx templates into razor syntax. Can anyone help me?

```
@{
bool ShouldShow(ModelMetadata metadata) {
    return metadata.ShowForDisplay
        && metadata.ModelType != typeof(System.Data.EntityState)
        && !metadata.IsComplexType
        && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(metadata);
    }
}

@if (Model == null) { 
    ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText
} else if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) {
    ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText
} else {
    foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => ShouldShow(pm))) {
    if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) {
        Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)
    } else {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(prop.GetDisplayName())) {
            <div class="display-label">@prop.GetDisplayName()</div>
        } 
        <div class="display-field">@Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)</div>
    } 
}
```

It's seems above code is correct (at least from my perspective).

**UPDATE**

I don't have any intellisense for ShouldShow method! why? I've a lot of compilation errors.

Error   1   } expected  PATH\Object.cshtml  1   1   PROJ
Error   5   A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods   PATH\Object.cshtml  11  3   PROJ
Error   4   Invalid token '}' in class, struct, or interface member declaration PATH\Object.cshtml  11  1   PROJ
and so on!

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Is there an error? If so, can you post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert class-level members (such as your `bool ShouldShow`), you need to use an [`@functions` block](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-6-function-blocks.html).